# Problem with data in Mediawiki's api (probably in js syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am using snippet from [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#Sample_code) marked as **MediaWiki JS** in my script:

```js
 const params = {
        action: "parse",
        page: stronaDyskusji,
        prop: "wikitext",
        section: index_sekcji,
    };
    const api = new mw.Api();

    api.get(params).done((data) => {
       console.log(data.parse.wikitext["*"]);
    });
```

everything work fine and i can see data in console. But when I want to do this like that
in order to process data it returns undefined.

```js
var zwrot;
    const params = {
        action: "parse",
        page: stronaDyskusji,
        prop: "wikitext",
        section: index_sekcji,
    };
    const api = new mw.Api();

    api.get(params).done((data) => {
        zwrot = data.parse.wikitext["*"];
    });
    console.log(zwrot);
```

Can you tell me pleas why or give me link to article, so i can learn myself how to work with this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `api.get().done()` is probably asynchronous

Means it takes either a callback function or it returns a promise that needs to be resolved. In your case the function takes a callback function which gets called once `api.get().done()` has finished processing. Callbacks are often used to continue code execution after an asynchronous operation has completed (like in this case).

#### First example

```js
api.get(params).done((data) => {
  console.log(data.parse.wikitext["*"]);
});
```

In your first code example, you are logging inside the callback function, means it will log after `api.get().done()` has finished.

#### Second example

```js
var zwrot;
api.get(params).done((data) => {
  zwrot = data.parse.wikitext["*"];
});
console.log(zwrot);
```

In your second example you are trying to log the value of `zwart` **before** the callback function has been triggered. Therefore, no value has been assigned to `zwart` yet. So it logs `undefined`

( Read more about [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/asynchronous) )

Comment: Could you pleas give me some solition to this problem? Or link to page I can read to understand this?

Comment: Read more about [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/asynchronous) - I already gave you an explanation to the problem you are facing . If you need a solution to a specific different problem please update your question .